# Button look like a Frame

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin forms, I have a frame  with a text and image, but the frame doesnt have a ripple effect, is possible to have a button look a frame?

Here is my example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FlexButton NuGet Package](https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/flexbutton). You can set the BorderRadius, have a RippleEffect, add Images.

```
<flex:FlexButton
    WidthRequest="76"
    HeightRequest="76"
    CornerRadius="38"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Icon="lightbulb.png"
    ForegroundColor="#ffffff"
    HighlightForegroundColor="#49516F"
    BackgroundColor="#6279B8"
    HighlightBackgroundColor="#8EA4D2" />
```

Comment: With this button is not possible to have the Image on Top and text on bottom.